# How to inject joined object in doctrine 2 using query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have Article and Category entities.
That entities not related by mapping but i need join Category to Article using query builder and as result i need Article entity with injected in Category entity. How i can do that?

I searched Google but did not find a solution

```
class ArticleRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Article::class);
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('articles')
            ->select('articles, category')
            ->join(\App\Entity\Category::class, 'category', 'WITH', 'articles.categoryId = category.id')
            ->getQuery();

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($query->getResult());
        exit;
    }
?>

// output

Array
(
    [0] => App\Entity\Article Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Article:private] => 1
            [name:App\Entity\Article:private] => title1
            [text:App\Entity\Article:private] => text1
            [categoryId:App\Entity\Article:private] => 1
            [categories:App\Entity\Article:private] => 
        )

    [1] => App\Entity\Category Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Category:private] => 1
            [name:App\Entity\Category:private] => first cat
        )

    [2] => App\Entity\Article Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Article:private] => 2
            [name:App\Entity\Article:private] => title2
            [text:App\Entity\Article:private] => text2
            [categoryId:App\Entity\Article:private] => 1
            [categories:App\Entity\Article:private] => 
        )

    [3] => App\Entity\Article Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Article:private] => 3
            [name:App\Entity\Article:private] => title3
            [text:App\Entity\Article:private] => text3
            [categoryId:App\Entity\Article:private] => 2
            [categories:App\Entity\Article:private] => 
        )

    [4] => App\Entity\Category Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Category:private] => 2
            [name:App\Entity\Category:private] => second cat
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
 ->select('articles.id','articles.name','articles.text','articles.categoryId','articles.categories','category.id', 'category.name')
```

instead of

```
->select('articles, category')
```

Comment: Thank you for comment but i get following error: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 80 near 'categories, categories.name': Error: Class App\Entity\Article has no field or association named categories" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/pronet/website-skeleton/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 65